# Error inserting array of objects

Tags: laravel-5

I get an array and it has to be swept and inserted into my database.

Array example that I will receive in the request:

```
{
"member_id": "1",
 "lista": [
 {
 "member_id": "1",
 "instituicao": "Teste",
 "data_inicio": "2018-04-01T03:00:00.000Z",
 "data_termino": "2018-04-01T03:00:00.000Z",
 "serie": "4",
 "cidade": "Salvador",
 "tipo": "fundamental"
},
{
 "member_id": "1",
 "instituicao": "Teste",
 "data_inicio": "2018-04-09T03:00:00.000Z",
 "data_termino": "2018-04-09T03:00:00.000Z",
 "curso": "Teologia",
 "cidade": "Salvador",
 "tipo": "superior"
 }
]
}
```

How to set in my controller to scan and insert in the bank:

```
     public function store(AcademicoRequest $request){
        $res= $request->all();
        foreach($res as $value) {
         Academico::create($value);
        }
      return response()->json($res);
      }
```

When trying to insert, the same fails.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly a guess but I don't think the `array_add` is quite right.
Because Laravel does not seem to have a bulk insert you might need to resort to just doing this.

```
foreach ($res->lista as $insertAcademic) {
    Academico::create($insertAcademic));
}
```

Not quite sure how you want to display the multiple created things though. Might need to do another query or append the results of create.

Comment: When using foreach this way: Trying to get property of non-object